# how important is the Divergence theorem in PDE theory?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question

let's start with topics I have quite good command of :

Hilbert spaces,
 Measure theory,
functional analysis/operator theory

topics I totally don't : 
vector calculus

so I was studying PDE's using Strauss's book in conjunction with Evans book and it was going well until I dove into green's functions.

it seems that the divergence theorem is used to show some identities.

since I don't really have much free time I'd like to know what's the minimum necessary of vector calculus that I should review before proceeding away ?

also if you have any specific reference to recommend me it would be great. thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which chapters you focus on, for most applications those identities are the important one. Let $u,v:\Omega \subset\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be sufficently smooth, integrable function s.t. all requirements for the divergence theorem are met and $\phi\in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Also, let $\Omega$ be a compact domain with smooth enough boundary.

1) Applying the divergence theorem to the function $f=u\phi e_i$, where $e_i$ denotes the $i$-th canonical basis vector. Then you have: 
$$
\int_{\Omega}div(f)dx=\int_{\Omega}u_i\phi+u\phi_idx=\int_{\partial \Omega}f \cdot n \;dS=0
$$
which implies:
$$
\int_{\Omega}u_i\phi=-\int_{\Omega}u\phi_idx
$$
This is an "integration by parts identity" used for defining weak solutions and studying sobolev spaces as well as acquiring integral indentities.

2)The second is applying the divergence theorem to $f=v\nabla u$ which gives you greens identity:
$$
\int_{\Omega} div(f)dx=\int_{\Omega} v \Delta u + \nabla u\cdot\nabla v \; dx=\int_{\partial\Omega} f \cdot n \; dS=\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}v \; dS
$$
In one line:
$$
\int_{\Omega} v \Delta u + \nabla u\cdot\nabla v \; dx=\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}v \; dS
$$
which is greens second identity. It is often used for studying equations involving the laplacian.

Those are the 2 most important applications. Apart from that, any calculus II/III books should cover you. I personally used Analysis II+III by Amann and Escher.